# returning an iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

How i return iterator form function :

i worte this :
.
..

```
template<class S,class T> class Database {
public:
.
..
 map<S,Node<T>*> m_map::iterator Find (S keyToFind);
.
..
....


private:
.
..
 map<S,Node<T>*> m_map;
..
.
};

.
..
template<class S,class T>
map<S,Node<T>*> m_map::iterator Find (S keyToFind) {
 map<S,Node<T>*>::iterator itMap;
 itMap = m_map.find(KeyToUpDate);
 return itMap;
}
..
.
```

there are many error because this :
Error 1 error C2653: 'm_map' : is not a class or namespace name
Error 2 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Find'
Error 3 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-
Error 5 error C2653: 'm_map' : is not a class or namespace name
Error 7 error C2133: 'iterator' : unknown size
..
...

i don't understand what is the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be:

```
template<class S,class T>
typename map<S,Node<T>*>::iterator Find(S keyToFind) {
    typename map<S,Node<T>*>::iterator itMap;
    itMap = m_map.find(KeyToUpDate);
    return itMap;
}
```

and

```
typename map<S,Node<T>*>::iterator Find (S keyToFind);
```

`typename` is needed because `iterator` is a dependent type, see e.g. [here](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation).

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you want:

```
typename map<S,Node<T>*>::iterator
```

You should *really* use typedef's to clean this stuff up:

```
template<class S, class T>
class Database
{
public:
    // I hope you have't put `using namespace std;` in a header...
    typedef std::map<S, Node<T>*> map_type;
    typedef typename map_type::iterator iterator;
    // etc...

    // use references to avoid copying
    iterator Find (const S& keyToFind);
private:
    map_type m_map;
};
```

Comment: First comment should be "I hope you have NOT put 'using namespace std' in a header." I hope.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Find` function should be defined as:

```
template<class S,class T>
typename map<S,Node<T>*>::iterator Find (S keyToFind) {
    map<S,Node<T>*>::iterator itMap;
    itMap = m_map.find(KeyToUpDate);
    return itMap;
}
```

without the " m_map" that you had as part of the function's return type.

**Edit:**  Though actually, there's no need to create the temporary `itMap` iterator; you can return the result of `find` directly.  Also, I think that `KeyToUpDate` should instead be `keyToFind`.  Making those modifications, you'd end up with:

```
template<class S,class T>
typename map<S,Node<T>*>::iterator Find (S keyToFind) {
    return m_map.find(keyToFind);
}
```